# Problem on returning fields of a struct inside a mapping

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have the above code

```
   mapping(string => Owner) public Owners;

    function addOwner( string memory name, string memory surname, string memory fathername, string memory mothername, string memory ethnicityId, string memory id) public returns(int8)
    {
        Owner memory owner;
        owner.name = name;
        owner.surname = surname;
        owner.fathername = fathername;
        owner.mothername = mothername;
        owner.ethnicityId = ethnicityId;
        owner.id = id;

        Owners[id] = owner;
        return 0;
    }

    function getOwnerName(string memory id) public returns(string memory, string memory) {
        Owner storage owner = Owners[id];
        return (owner.name, owner.surname);
    }
```

I am inserting an Owner with addOwner and try to retrieve with getOwnerName but Ringeby network is not returning the data I have inserted. The function returns the right data when I use the javascript VM on remix IDE

Comment: Can you point us to the deployed contract on Rinkeby? The code is fine (as you already know because it works in Remix), so presumably there's something wrong with how you're executing it on Rinkeby.

Comment: I must declare the getOwnerName function as view answer by https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/69373/51981

Comment: Ah, quite right. Sorry I missed that!